# Is the variance of residuals really constant?

Tags: regression, residuals

Variance of a residual, conditioned on $x$, is constant, but is still a function of $x$. The farther the $x$ is from $\overline{x}$, the bigger the variance (page 3, equation 9 from these [notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/07/lecture-07.pdf)).

So when plotting the residuals, why should we expect to see "constant-width blur of points around
a straight, flat line at height zero" (page 7 from the same notes)? I would expect to see a curvature -- where, as we move away from $\overline{x}$, the spread increases in both directions.

Comment: Are you thinking about the true variance ($\sigma^{2}_{y|x}$), or the sample variance ($\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{y|x}$)?

Comment: The model assumes that for the true variance and if the model is approximately correct you have it nearly constant.

Comment: Alexis, I believe it's the true variance that the notes are referring to.

Michael, I can buy that argument. Thanks! I wish the notes would address that point explicitly.